# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState':

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, hive, apache-spark-2.0

I'm trying to connect to Hive through Intelliji. I'm using Scala version 2.11.4,the version of spark-core,spark-hive,spark-sql are 2.1.1.  here is the code snippt I'm using to connect remotely from my windows m/c. While connecting I'm getting following error, can someone help me to address this issue?

Note: when I read some threads, they mentioned about checking the permission of tmp, in this case, /tmp/hive/warehouse. it has appropriate permission to the user xyz I'm using to connect. using this functional id, I'm able to manually connect from one of the unix server.  I even tried with spark.sql("show databases") but it was the same error.

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    createKerberosTicket()
    val spark: SparkSession = {
          SparkSession
            .builder()
            .master("local")
            .appName("SparkHiveTest")
            .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict")
            .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true")
            .config("mapreduce.job.queuename", "root.XYZ_Pool")
            .enableHiveSupport()
            .getOrCreate()
        }
    spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.addResource(new Path("core-site.xml"))
    spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.addResource(new Path("hdfs-site.xml"))
    spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.addResource(new Path("hive-site.xml"))
    spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.hdfs.impl", classOf[DistributedFileSystem].getName)
    spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.file.impl", classOf[LocalFileSystem].getName)
    val listOfDBs = spark.sqlContext.sql("show databases")
}

18/05/02 23:59:13 INFO SharedState: spark.sql.warehouse.dir is not set, but hive.metastore.warehouse.dir is set. Setting spark.sql.warehouse.dir to the value of hive.metastore.warehouse.dir ('/tmp/hive/warehouse').
18/05/02 23:59:13 INFO SharedState: Warehouse path is '/tmp/hive/warehouse'.
18/05/02 23:59:14 INFO HiveUtils: Initializing HiveMetastoreConnection version 1.2.1 using Spark classes.
18/05/02 23:59:14 INFO metastore: Trying to connect to metastore with URI thrift://xyz.net:1234
18/05/02 23:59:14 INFO metastore: Connected to metastore.
18/05/02 23:59:18 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState':
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.org$apache$spark$sql$SparkSession$$reflect(SparkSession.scala:981)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState$lzycompute(SparkSession.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState(SparkSession.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$getOrCreate$5.apply(SparkSession.scala:878)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$getOrCreate$5.apply(SparkSession.scala:878)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:99)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:99)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:230)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:878)
    at spark.SparkPlusHive$.main(SparkPlusHive.scala:25)
    at spark.SparkPlusHive.main(SparkPlusHive.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.org$apache$spark$sql$SparkSession$$reflect(SparkSession.scala:978)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog':
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState$.org$apache$spark$sql$internal$SharedState$$reflect(SharedState.scala:169)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.<init>(SharedState.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$sharedState$1.apply(SparkSession.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$sharedState$1.apply(SparkSession.scala:101)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sharedState$lzycompute(SparkSession.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sharedState(SparkSession.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SessionState.<init>(SessionState.scala:157)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState.<init>(HiveSessionState.scala:32)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState$.org$apache$spark$sql$internal$SharedState$$reflect(SharedState.scala:166)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.createClient(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:358)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:262)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.<init>(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:66)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:522)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.<init>(HiveClientImpl.scala:188)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1012)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:505)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:478)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:738)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:831)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:814)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:712)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkOneDirWithMode(RawLocalFileSystem.java:470)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirsWithOptionalPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:510)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirs(RawLocalFileSystem.java:488)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.mkdirs(FilterFileSystem.java:309)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createPath(SessionState.java:639)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createSessionDirs(SessionState.java:567)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:508)
    ... 39 more
```

Answer (score 0):

> 18/05/02 23:59:13 INFO SharedState: spark.sql.warehouse.dir is not
>   set,

it is clear that your `spark.sql.warehouse.dir` is not set please set that to erase the above issue

```
val warehouseLocation = "file:${system:user.dir}/spark-warehouse"
    val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .appName("***")
    .master("***")
    .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouseLocation)
    .enableHiveSupport()
    .getOrCreate()
```

hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks for the response.I set spark.sql.warehouse.dir to file:///C:/tmp/hive/warhouse but still the same issue. should this be a local path where I'm running spark?

Comment: look i ahave given a local path and its working for me can you please try the same

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, it's worked by following [here](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-tips-and-tricks-running-spark-windows.html).

- download the winutils.exe.
- set the env variable HADOOP_HOME.
- make dir 'C:\tmp\hive', used as the Spark property value 'spark.sql.warehouse.dir'.
- change permission of the dir 'C:\tmp\hive' to 777.